# Airflow helm chart 1.7 - Mounting DAGs from an externally populated PVC and non-default DAG path

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pvc

I want to use Airflow in Kubernetes on my local machine.
From the [Airflow helm chart doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/manage-dags-files.html#mounting-dags-from-an-externally-populated-pvc) I should use a PVC to use my local DAG files, so I setup my PV and PVC like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: dags-pv
spec:
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClassName: local-path
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/c/Users/me/dags
    type: Directory
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dags-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: local-path
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

Then I create a override-values.yaml file

```
config:
  core:
    dags_folder: "/usr/somepath/airflow/dags"
    
dags:
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    existingClaim: "dags-pvc"
  gitSync:
    enabled: false
```

Note here that I want to change the default DAG folder path. And that's where I am having difficulties (it works if I keep the default DAG folder path). I don't know how to create a mount point and attach the PVC to it.

I tried to add, in my override file:

```
worker:
  extraVolumeMounts:                                                                                                                                                            
  - name: w-dags
    mountPath: "/usr/somepath/airflow/dags"

  extraVolumes:
  - name: w-dags
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: "dags-pvc"
      
scheduler:
  extraVolumeMounts:                                                                                                                                                            
  - name: s-dags
    mountPath: "/usr/somepath/airflow/dags"

  extraVolumes:
  - name: s-dags
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: "dags-pvc"
```

But that doesn't work, my scheduler is stuck on Init:0/1: "Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[dags], unattached volumes=[logs dags s-dags config kube-api-access-9mc4c]: timed out waiting for the condition". So, I can tell I broke a condition - dags should be mounted  (aka my extraVolumes section is wrong) - but I am not sure where to go from here.